# $httpBackend with AngularJS/Jasmine - why mock a response?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

The AngularJS tutorials say that when using $httpBackend a response should be mocked. What I'm unsure about is why would I want to mock a request to an API when I could just use $http and make the request and retrieve the 'real' data? I can then run the test on the actual response, this allows to check if data response from the API has changed (for what ever reason). However, if I was mocking the response and the API data changes, then my mock response will be different to the actual response. Therefore making the tests incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You got it right. There are (at least) three types of tests:

> 1. Unit tests
> 2. Integration tests
> 3. System tests

You can find a nice explanation [here](http://www.typemock.com/unit-tests-integration-tests).

*Everybody defines those tests different*. My perspective is:

> 1. **Unit tests** are testing a module/each function separately.
> 2. **Integration tests** are testing a whole workflow ("Fill out registration form > sending data to backend > receiving token >
>      login")
> 3. **System testing** - for me - is: Use cases in the Front End. Example: Can a user login and will present with the user profile after entering his credentials.

What you are describing is a Unit test. Therefore, testing if your function is performing an API call is enough. Also test if you call a certain URL and sending the correct data.

**Remember: You often times run tests with every change in your code. 
Therefore, it would be quite too much to always call the real API.**

[From the Angular docs:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

> During unit testing, we want our unit tests to run quickly and have no
>   external dependencies so we don’t want to send XHR or JSONP requests
>   to a real server. All we really need is to verify whether a certain
>   request has been sent or not, or alternatively just let the
>   application make requests, respond with pre-trained responses and
>   assert that the end result is what we expect it to be.

You can test this with [$httpBackend.expect](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#expect).

**So, what if your API endpoint is changing the structure of the data?**

1. Get sure you are testing the backend and get sure you send the data as defined
2. Write an integration test where you check the data flow through a certain process (login, receiving data for a dashboard etc.)

In the end, there is no bullet proof concept. But those steps and mentality is already a good proof for a fairly big project.

Answer (score 0):

**Jasmine** is an **unit test** framework.

If you use `$http` directly, you won't test an unique component, you will test at the same time your API. If your API is down, your test will fail.

It is cleaner to **test your components individualy**.

**More :**

- `$httpbackend` allows you to try test case that your API doesn't offer. So you can build robust applications.
- `$http` can take time to resolve, when `$httpbackend` can resolve all the request just by asking :

  ```
  httpBackend.flush();
  ```

etc.